# Concatenate absolute file paths in string

Tags: java, concatenation, filepath

I need to concatenate several absolute file paths in one string. 
But if I use character, that can be a part of file name or path the string will be messed. Which separator can be used?

Now I use File.pathSeparator and for Windows 7 it is ';'.
But this character can be a part of file name.

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869594/semi-colons-in-windows-filenames)

[Semicolons are legal in NTFS file paths.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why don't you use a collection in the first place?

Comment: I'm thinking about pipe symbol now, but I'm not sure about other file systems.
And still interested while File.pathSeparator returned ';' but path can contain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [File.pathSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator):

> The system-dependent path-separator character, represented as a string
>   for convenience. This string contains a single character, namely [pathSeparatorChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar):
>
> *The system-dependent path-separator character. This field is
>   initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system
>   property path.separator. This character is used to separate filenames
>   in a sequence of files given as a path list. On UNIX systems, this
>   character is ':'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is ';'.*

Comment: I use it now. But file names in Windows 7, for example, can have ';'.

Comment: Unfortunately no, while the path separator is used to separate paths there's nothing that stops you from using a colon in a file name on Unix.

Comment: @YegoshinMaxim You can check whether the path until `;` exists, if not, then you know it's part of a file name. BTW, I'm working with it for long time and never encountered a file with `;` in its name.

Comment: To create a file called `;.:*?<>|\^` on Linux, use `touch ';.:*?<>|\^'`

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII NUL character `\0` cannot be a part of a pathname on Windows or Unix (including Mac), so you probably can use that as a separator.

The NUL character can't be used in a file path because it is the string terminator character in C, and the APIs for these operating systems are defined as a C libraries that use strings to represent file paths.

If you want to use a printable character as a separator you'll have to use an escape code scheme. One of the simplest is doubling the separator: suppose you use # as the separator; to add a path to the list you replace any # already present in the path with ##.